# PowerBI: Recuento de elementos de un tabla en función del número de apariciones en otra

Tags: mysql, powerbi, ciencia-de-datos, dax

Tengo la siguiente consulta en MySQL:

```
SELECT
    concat(substring(ano, 1, 3), 0) AS decada,
    nombre_pais,
    nombre_ciudad,
    count(nombre_ciudad) AS numero
FROM
    paises
        NATURAL JOIN ciudades
            NATURAL JOIN autores
                NATURAL JOIN publican
                    NATURAL JOIN discos
                        NATURAL JOIN canciones
                            NATURAL JOIN listas_spotify
GROUP BY
    decada,
    nombre_ciudad
```

El campo `ano` se encuentra en `listas_spotify`, de ahí que haya que recorrer tantas tablas. Lo que hago es comprobar cuántas veces aparece por década cada ciudad en función de las veces que hay registradas canciones de artistas de esa ciudad en la base de datos.

Si ordenamos el resultado por `numero`, por ejemplo, queda una tabla con el siguiente aspecto:

```
decada, nombre_pais, nombre_ciudad, numero
1980, Inglaterra, Londres, 23
1990, Inglaterra, Londres, 15
1980, Inglaterra, Mánchester, 11
2000, EEUU, Austin, 11
2000, EEUU, Nueva York, 10
1980, EEUU, Boston, 9
1980, EEUU, Nueva York, 8
1990, Inglaterra, Mánchester, 7
1990, Inglaterra, Oxford, 7
...
```

Por ejemplo, en la década de los 80 hay 23 canciones de diferentes años y artistas cuya ciudad es Londres.

He cargado esta base de datos en PowerBI y estoy intentando reproducir estos resultados utilizando DAX. Huelga decir que no tengo ni idea de por dónde empezar. El objetivo es hacer un gráfico tal que así (lo he hecho cargando directamente la tabla que genera MySQL y filtrando para cinco ciudades importantes):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo de datos en PowerBI es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado partir de la tabla `ciudades` pero la verdad es que no sé ni cómo hacer un recuento del numero de apariciones en función de la tabla `autores`.

A ver si me podéis orientar al respecto. Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolverlo de una forma que me parece muy chapucera, porque implica crear 8 tablas intermedias; quizá se puedan crear de forma temporal, de manera que no se añadan al modelo. Si alguien sabe cómo, le agradecería un comentario al respecto.

Partiendo de la tabla `listas_spotify`, mediante `NATURALINNERJOIN()` con la tabla `canciones`:

```
tabla_1 = 
VAR tabla1 = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                            'listas_spotify',
                            "id_lista", [id_lista_spotify] & "",
                            "decada", [decada]
)
VAR tabla2 = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                            'canciones',
                            "id_lista", [id_lista_spotify] & "",
                            "cancion", [titulo_cancion],
                            "id_cancion", [id_cancion]
)
RETURN NATURALINNERJOIN(tabla1, tabla2)
```

Así hasta llegar a:

```
tabla_7 = 
VAR tabla1 = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                            'tabla_6',
                            "id_pais", [id_pais] & "",
                            "decada", [decada],
                            "cancion", [cancion],
                            "ciudad", [ciudad]
)
VAR tabla2 = SELECTCOLUMNS(
                            'paises',
                            "id_pais", [id_pais] & "",
                            "pais", [nombre_pais]
)
RETURN NATURALINNERJOIN(tabla1, tabla2)
```

Elimino el `id_pais`:

```
tabla_final = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
                'tabla_7',
                "decada", [decada],
                "titulo_cancion", [cancion],
                "nombre_ciudad", [ciudad],
                "nombre_pais", [pais]
)
```

Y agrupo mediante `SUMMARIZE()`:

```
tabla_agrupada = 
SUMMARIZE(
            tabla_final, 
            tabla_final[decada], 
            tabla_final[nombre_ciudad], 
            tabla_final[nombre_pais], 
            "apariciones", 
            COUNT(tabla_final[titulo_cancion])
)
```

Y así se vería el gráfico para las ciudades más representativas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me comentan en el SO Internacional que sería posible crear esa tabla en PowerQuery sin necesidad de añadir todas las intermedias al modelo.